# redis_client/command_builder.rb:37:in `block in generate': Unsupported command argument type: ActiveSupport::Duration (TypeError)

Tags: sidekiq

When upgrading from Sidekiq 6 to Sidekiq 7, and you are using the `sidekiq-status` gem, you'll potentially run into the following error depending on how you configured `sidekiq-status`.

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-client-0.14.1/lib/redis_client/command_builder.rb:37:in `block in generate': Unsupported command argument type: ActiveSupport::Duration (TypeError)
```

Solution to this issue provided below:

Answer (score 2):

If you are running into this issue, it's highly probable your configuration of `sidekiq-status` looks something like the following:

```rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ServerMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes
  end
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = sidekiq_config if ENV['REDIS_URL']
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes
  end
end
```

The primary issue with this configuration is how `expiration` will now be interpreted when this configuration is instantiated. It's now necessary to pass this configuration as an `integer` instead of an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object. The following configuration should fix the error:

```rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ServerMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes.to_i
  end
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes.to_i
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = sidekiq_config if ENV['REDIS_URL']
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes.to_i
  end
end
```